# ¿Como instalar en local, un proyecto en Laravel 5.8 que esta en producción con un paquete que ya no existe?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mercadopago, composer, sdk

tengo un problemilla y voy a  tratar de explicarlo claro y de antemano gracias por la ayuda comunidad.

Me dieron un proyecto en Laravel 5.8 en producción en Digital Ocean, me pidieron hacer unas modificaciones, entonces lo que hice, fue subirlo a un repositorio de github y luego lo clone a mi maquina local para poder  hacer las modificaciones.

El problema esta que al hacer el composer install en mi maquina local hay un paquete de mercadopago/sdk v0.5.3 que al parecer ya no esta disponible (mercado pago actualizo sus ligas y esta la despareció)

Entonces no puedo hacer la instalacion en local,

-¿Como podría hacer para instalar un paquete que ya no existe?

-Tengo la carpeta completa del proyecto ¿puedo copiar el paquete de manera manual del proyecto original a mi maquina local?

-Lo que tengo duda después (si lograra hacerlo manual) como sincronizo de local a github para que no haya conflictos al combinar con el original, ya que si decidiera borrar el original y reinstalar por el modificado tendría el mismo problema del paquete que ya no existe

NOTA: De momento no puedo subir la versión la del framework porque tiene varios paquetes de terceros que se quedaron hasta la versión 5 de laravel

Lo que menos me gustaría seria tener que rehacer y programar todo de nuevo (obvio no me van pagar lo que equivaldría eso)

De antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 0):

> Tengo la carpeta completa del proyecto ¿puedo copiar el paquete de manera manual del proyecto original a mi maquina local?

Sí puedes, pero copiarlo directo a la carpeta `vendor` no serviría: el autoloader no lo tendrá incorporado. A menos, claro, que copies y nunca más toques  la carpeta `vendor`, el `composer.json` y el `composer.lock`. No suena bien.

Lo que podrías hacer, en cambio, es **(paso 1)** copiarlo a otra carpeta (por ejemplo `./resources/packages/`, de modo que si hoy está en `./vendor/mercadopago/sdk`, quede en `./resources/packages/mercadopago/sdk`)

Y luego **(paso 2)**, decirle a composer [que no lo pida a packagist sino a la ruta](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) donde lo dejaste usando la propiedad "repositories"

```
{ 
  "name": "my_organization/my_app",
  ... etc etc...
  "require": {
     "mercadopago/sdk":"^0.5.3",
     ...etc etc 
    },
  "repositories": [{
        "type": "path",
        "url": "resources/packages/mercadopago/sdk",
        "options": {
          "symlink": true
        }
      }],
  ...etc etc
}
```

(es opcional decirle que haga un symlink en vez de copiar a `vendor`. Es práctico cuando estás haciendo cambios en un paquete).

Finalmente **(paso 3)**, ponle `composer require "mercadopago/sdk":"^0.5.3"`para que el `composer.lock` se actualice. (y también el autoloader)

Y **(paso 5)** buscar el paso 4 que no existe. Los tres primeros son todo.

> Lo que tengo duda después (si lograra hacerlo manual) como sincronizo de local a github para que no haya conflictos al combinar con el original, ya que si decidiera borrar el original y reinstalar por el modificado tendría el mismo problema del paquete que ya no existe

Debieras limitar la modificación a lo que describo arriba. Tu commit contiene una modificación a `composer.json` y a `composer.lock`, más la adición del directorio `resources/packages/mercadopago/sdk`. Lo pusheas a github, y cuando hagas `git pull` desde DigitalOcean hará un fast-forward común y corriente, que te dejará el nuevo directorio listo para que ejecutes `composer install` sin buscar el paquete en packagist.

**Se puede usar algo que no sea copiar la dependencia en el proyecto?**

Claro, puedes versionar `mercadopago/sdk`, subirlo a github y requerirlo en composer con algo tipo

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/luis_bautista/mercadopago_sdk_reloaded"
    }
]
```

Pero en ese caso tendrías que dejarlo público o prepararte para un tortuoso camino que está fuera del scope de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

De preferncia ya no lo deberías usar, lo que si puedes hacer es migrarlo a la "nueva" versión que liberaron, así podrás continuar usando los servicios del SDK, te dejo el link:

[Mercado Pago SDK for PHP](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php)

M